# how to copy numbers from camera lenses and put this copy in another app?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

my problem that I want to make an app read numbers from camera lenses we return a copy to my app.

like you have a number on piece of paper
I want to open my app and it will open camera lenses and read this number by camera lenses and return me a copy of that number to my app

Comment: When you say "number" what exactly do you mean? Do you mean the focal length, the SKU, ...? Additionally, are you asking how to use Optical Character Recognition (OCR) to read words off the camera lens?

Comment: no what I mean is simple , I mean number like 234648474644540
I just want take a copy of this number to my app

Comment: You mean using the phone's camera, pointing it at an object, and interpreting the text on the object?

Comment: If that's what you mean, this is probably the library you should be using: http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2014/09/18/microsoft-ocr-library-for-windows-runtime/

Comment: exactly :)
this is what I mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optical Character Recognition can be done through Windows Phone using the Microsoft OCR Library for Windows Runtime: http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2014/09/18/microsoft-ocr-library-for-windows-runtime/.

Here's a sample application which demonstrates how to use the library: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Uses-the-OCR-Library-to-2a9f5bf4