# Using phone camera to scan and extract text in web app

Tags: c#, .net

I am making a .net web app. My attempt of taking a picture and trying to extract text from that picture has a terrible success rate. I see apps that let you scan a page into pdf. I want to use that approach using the users phone camera. I need help identifying the best free APIs that will help accomplish this.

I don't have any code yet; I don't want you to do it for me rather just help me find the resource. I'm new to this and here to learn and get educated.

Comment: are you familiar with OCR do some google searching on that topic in regards to implementing it with C#

Comment: I have and I am, I just don't see how to scan with the phone camera. Most things I saw was with real scanners. I am currently using Tesseract.Net.SDK package, I have played with Asprise too

Comment: Then how come I was able to do a simple google search to find this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26577110/how-to-copy-numbers-from-camera-lenses-and-put-this-copy-in-another-app check the links in the accepted answer.. good luck

Comment: on the surface seems to target windows apps only, i'll try it out tho. thank you

Comment: Olay,

The reason you are getting down voted is because there are multiple resources out there that only require a quick google search for 'open source android ocr' and it will come up with relevant results that answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most popular open source ocr solution is Tesseract.
Here are 2 github links to Android and IOS open source solutions using Tesseract:

- [Android Github project](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two)
- [iOS Github project](https://github.com/gali8/Tesseract-OCR-iOS/wiki/Using-Tesseract-OCR-iOS)